# Are fingerprints stored in biometric checks?

Tags: biometrics

There is a digital banking app for increasing wallet limits. We can verify our fingerprint with this feature.

My question is, is it safe to use? I mean are they going to store my fingerprint and then perform some verification?

Comment: Welcome to the community. As with any biometrics based identification system, the biometric data needs to be stored in order to compare it with the received input. Now if the data gets stolen, biometric data is not like a password - it cannot simply be changed... That's the main argument against such authentication systems.

Comment: It wouldn't matter if it was touchless or not, so I removed that element. Neither does it matter what the app does that requires the biometrics. And I refined your question to what you actually ask, which is about storing biometric data.